# Using a string output to set identifier

Tags: vb.net, model-view-controller, sqldatareader, sqlconnection

```
Public Class Functions
    Inherits BaseClass
    Public Function KesDetails(KesID As Integer) As KesH

        Dim Sql As New SqlClass
        Dim lRd As DataTableReader


        Sql.OpenConnection()

        Sql.lCmd.CommandText = " SELECT"
        Sql.lCmd.CommandText &= " Case WHEN KAHStatus = 'M' THEN 'LULUS'  ELSE cast(DATEDIFF(Day, KAHCreatedOn, GetDate()) as varchar(10)) END As DayCount"
        Sql.lCmd.CommandText &= " ,KAHID,KAH_AKJID,KAHCreatedBy,KAHCreatedOn"
        Sql.lCmd.CommandText &= " ,KAHLokasi,KAHHirarki,KAHPenjaga,KAHBertanggungjawab,KAHInden,KAHMelulus,KAH_KAJID,KAJNAMA,G.FPNoTender,G.FPNoKontrak,G.FPTajukProjek,G.FPKontrakNamaSyarikat,KAHUpdatedOn"
        Sql.lCmd.CommandText &= " FROM HartaMajlis..KejuruteraanArahanH A "
        Sql.lCmd.CommandText &= " LEFT JOIN HartaMajlis..KejuruteraanArahanProd B ON A.KAH_KAPID=B.KAPID"
        Sql.lCmd.CommandText &= " LEFT JOIN HartaMajlis..AduanKejuruteraan C ON A.KAH_AKJID=C.AKJProjekID"
        Sql.lCmd.CommandText &= " LEFT JOIN hartamajlis..hartabangunan D ON C.AKJ_ITEMID = D.HTBgnID"
        Sql.lCmd.CommandText &= " LEFT JOIN hartamajlis..KejuruteraanArahanJenis E ON A.KAH_KAJID = E.KAJID"
        Sql.lCmd.CommandText &= " LEFT JOIN hartamajlis..KejuruteraanArahanHirarki F ON A.KAHHirarki = F.KAHHID"
        Sql.lCmd.CommandText &= " LEFT JOIN hartamajlis..FailProjek G ON F.KAHH_FKJTenderNo = G.FPNoTender"
        Sql.lCmd.CommandText &= " WHERE A.KAHDeleted<>'Y'"
        Sql.lCmd.CommandText &= " AND A.KAHID = " & KesID
        Sql.lCmd.CommandText &= " ORDER BY A.KAHUpdatedON DESC"

        lRd = Sql.QueryData().CreateDataReader

        Dim lsData As New KesH

        If lRd.Read() Then
            'lsData.DayCount = Convert.ToString(lRd("DayCount"))
            'lsData.KAHID = Convert.ToInt32(lRd("KAHID"))
            'lsData.KAH_AKJID = Convert.ToString(lRd("KAH_AKJID"))
            'lsData.KAHCreatedOn = Convert.ToString(lRd("KAHCreatedOn"))
            'lsData.KAHLokasi = Convert.ToString(lRd("KAHLokasi"))
            'lsData.KAHCreatedBy = Convert.ToString(lRd("KAHCreatedBy"))
            'lsData.KAHLokasi = Convert.ToString(lRd("KAHLokasi"))
            'lsData.KAHHirarki = Convert.ToString(lRd("KAHHirarki"))
            'lsData.KAHPenjaga = Convert.ToString(lRd("KAHPenjaga"))
            'lsData.KAHBertanggungjawab = Convert.ToString(lRd("KAHBertanggungjawab"))
            'lsData.KAHInden = Convert.ToString(lRd("KAHInden"))
            'lsData.KAHMelulus = Convert.ToString(lRd("KAHMelulus"))
            'lsData.KAH_KAJID = Convert.ToString(lRd("KAH_KAJID"))
            'lsData.KAJNAMA = Convert.ToString(lRd("KAJNAMA"))
            'lsData.FPKontrakNamaSyarikat = Convert.ToString(lRd("FPKontrakNamaSyarikat"))
            'lsData.FPNoKontrak = Convert.ToString(lRd("FPNoKontrak"))
            'lsData.FPNoTender = Convert.ToString(lRd("FPNoTender"))
            'lsData.KAHUpdatedOn = Convert.ToDateTime(lRd("KAHUpdatedOn"))

            Dim properties As PropertyInfo() = GetType(KesH).GetProperties()
            For Each Names As PropertyInfo In properties
                If Names.PropertyType = GetType(String) Or Names.PropertyType = GetType(Integer) Or Names.PropertyType = GetType(DateTime) Then
                    MsgBox(Names.Name & Names.PropertyType.ToString)
                    lsData.(Names.Name) = lRd(Names.Name)

                End If
            Next

        End If

        Sql.CloseConnection()
        Return lsData
    End Function
End Class
```

Instead of typing and declaring the variable and assign the lrd(...) one by one i made a loop function to assign, but 1 more thing missing is to declare the lsData using the output of name.Names , any idea how I can solve this, It's been 5 hour i try to solve this and scratched my head over and over again till bleeding, or is there any other way/method to loop this without declaring and assigning the lrd(...) . Thank you very much guys.

Answer (score 0):

Once you start using Reflection, you have to keep doing so.  You can't magically turn a `String` containing a name into an identifier.  You use the `PropertyInfo` object to set the property value on the object by calling its `SetValue` method, e.g.

```
myPropertyInfo.SetValue(targetObject, value)
```

That is equivalent to:

```
targetObject.MyProperty = value
```

Comment: thank you so much for the reply, I'll try to search for that , haven't messed with the setvalue before :))

Comment: by any chance do you have the idea to use the setvalue in my situation.

Comment: See the example I've added.